# Running a method in parallel with waiting

Tags: python

I have a function that generates a random reaction time and waits before printing out to the console.

Here is my code

```
import time
import random

def saySnap(player):
    reactionTime = random.randint(120, 401) / 1000
    time.sleep(reactionTime)
    print("{} : Snap!".format(player))

saySnap("p1")
saySnap("p2")
```

This results in 'p1' always being first since `time.sleep` blocks the program. How can I make sure that either player can print first?

Comment: You need to read about `threading` or `asyncio` depending on the case. The first will give you a way to execure CPU intensive tasks in parallel (then you will read about the GIL and see this is harder than it looks) the later will make the same for I/O bound tasks.

Comment: You want to use the standard module `asyncio` for this.

Comment: @yorodm thanks for the pointers, I'll definitely have a read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html):

```
import time
import random
import threading

def saySnap(player):
    reactionTime = random.randint(120, 401) / 1000
    time.sleep(reactionTime)
    print(f"{player}: Snapped in {reactionTime}!")


p1_thread = threading.Thread(target=saySnap, args=("p1",))
p2_thread = threading.Thread(target=saySnap, args=("p2",))
p1_thread.start()
p2_thread.start()
```

Which gives results randomly on your reaction times you set above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) class from built in `threading` module which represents an action that should be run only after a certain amount of time has passed.

Use:

```
import threading

def printSnap(player): # action that will be performed after reactionTime has been elapsed
     print("{} : Snap!".format(player))

def saySnap(player):
    reactionTime = random.randint(120, 401) / 1000
    # instantiate and start the timer.
    threading.Timer(reactionTime, printSnap, args=(player,)).start()
```

Or, if you don't want to define another function `printSnap`, Use:

```
def saySnap(player):
    reactionTime = random.randint(120, 401) / 1000
    threading.Timer(
        reactionTime, lambda p: print(f"{p} : Snap!"), args=(player,)).start()
```

Calling the function:

```
saySnap("p1")
saySnap("p2")
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a really neat way to shorten the solution by Treatybreaker